# When button is click then label is show in java frame

Tags: java

> I want to show when I clicking a **YES** button the **YES LABEL** is show
>    First I have created two panel
>
> Then two buttons are created then two labels are created Then create a
>   constructor that inside that two buttons

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
class myProgram extends Frame implements ActionListener{
// create two panels
Panel p1=new Panel();
Panel p2=new Panel();
// create two buttons 
Button yes=new Button("YES");
Button no=new Button("NO");
// create two labels
Label l1=new Label("YES LABEL");
Label l2=new Label("NO LABEL");
// create a constructor 
myProgram() {
//p2.add(l1);
p1.add(yes);
p1.add(no);
yes.addActionListener(this);
no.addActionListener(this);

Frame f=new Frame();
f.setSize(500,500);

f.add(p1);
f.add(p2);
f.setVisible(true);
        }       

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    String str = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(str.equals("YES")) {

        p2.add(l1);

    }
    else {

    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        myProgram p1=new myProgram();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at what `String str = ae.getActionCommand();` is when `actionPerformed` is called

Comment: p3 is not defined

Comment: Also, have a look a [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) to understand what's going on with your layout and why `p1` and `p3` aren't been displayed

Comment: You also might like to have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) as raw AWT is really, really, really out of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating 2 separate labels, create a single empty label, add it on panel 2 and use `label.setText(str)` in your `if` condition. Also, set layout for your frame to get proper output.

Highlighting your `if` condition here

```
if(str.equals("YES")) {
        System.out.println(str);
        label.setText(str);

    }
    else if(str.equals("NO")) {
        System.out.println(str);
        label.setText(str);
    }
```